# Simulink: read binary file from the 1st or from the 2nd bit

Tags: binary, simulink, bit

I have a binary file, from which I read a bit sequence (for a Viterbi decoder). In one case I simply read the file from the beginning (from the ***zero*** bit), but in another case, I have to read a bit sequence from the ***1st*** bit. 
Below is a part of my scheme:
[image: a part of Simulink scheme]
I cannot understand how it can be done.
It is also appropriate to me to delay the sequence for 1 bit (prepend one bit to the sequence), and tried do this using the elements [Delay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/delay.html), [Unit Delay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/unitdelay.html), [Tapped Delay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/tappeddelay.html). But I cannot undestand how to do it correctly.
What parameters I shall use for the Bibary File Reader and to the delays?
Now I use the *Samples per frame* parameter of the File Reader block equal to 262144, and Sample time is 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by adding a [Delay](https://www.mathworks.com/help/simulink/slref/delay.html) block with the following parameters:
[image]